# ¿ Cómo hacer click en un botón o una opción de action bar y muestre un pdf?

Tags: java, android

Puedo poner una dirección web y que me lleve a una pagina y se abra un archivo pero, yo quiero guardar dentro de la aplicación un archivo y que al apretar un botón me lo muestre, sin dirección web. Pues así evito que se baje el usuario una y otra vez el archivo llenando la memoria.

actualizado :

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ejemplo.pdf");//File path
if (pdfFile.exists()) //Checking for the file is exist or not
{
  Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
  Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
  objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(objIntent);//Staring the pdf viewer
} else {

  Toast.makeText(this, "The file not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

yo tengo eso pero no me sale, donde tengo que tener guardado el pdf para que se me muestre?

Comment: el archivo que me refiero es un PDF

Answer (score 1):

En éste caso lo mejor es que uses la clase [PdfRender](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html)

Te adjunto el código del  ejmplo de la docuemntación:

```
 // create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

Otra opción es la que antes comenté usando el componente [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) y llamando a una página que use la la librería javascript [Pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Viendo éste [ejemplo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/pdfrendererbasic/PdfRendererBasicFragment.java) tendrás más pistas para integrarlo en tu código ;-)

Comment: Ricardo,pero esto debo añadirlo en el onCreate y donde pongo mi documento pdf ? en " '../../build/pdf.worker.js' " no ? Y ya está?

Comment: Lo que yo me refiero... ¿ No puedo simplemente guardar el pdf dentro de carpeta raw o donde sea y llamar mediante un intent a ese pdf ?

Comment: Opsss disculpa, no me fijé en el tag android. Mi respuesta era más bien para renderizar un pdf en un navegador (Que también lo puedes hacer en android usando el componente WebView ;-) Cambio la respuesta. ;-)

Comment: mira mi actualizacion por favor, porque tu respuesta no consigo cuadrarla con lo mio.